# This post still needs 11 vote(s) from other users to delete

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I have always thought that a nice feature would be to pre-emptively un-delete or un-vote-to-close questions.  Some questions just polarize people and instead of having it cycle between close/delete/undelete/reopen, it would be nice to get people to simply cast their vote just like normal rep votes.

**Has this actually been implemented??**

See screenshot below

[image: 11 votes? you kidding?]

Comment: [The Great Question Deletion Audit of 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010) , [Should delete votes be limited like close votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes)

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54138/mission-impossible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more votes (question + answers) a question has, the more delete votes it takes. In this case, there are lots of votes for the question and its answers, so it requires lots of people to vote to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't preemptively vote against closing or deleting a question.  Deleting now depends partially on the vote tally of the question, so very highly rated questions can be readily closed, but not so easily deleted.